# Changing namespace separator from colon(:) to underscore (_) in Maya

Tags: python, maya

I have imported a file "test_v001.mb" with the namespace "hello". Is there a way where I can remove colon and replace it with underscore in the outliner?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

test_file = "D:/test/test_v001.mb"

cmds.file(test_file, i=True, typ='mayaBinary', ra=True, mnc=False, op="v=0;", ns="hello", pr=True, lrd="all")
```

In the screenshot below I have done manually for the third one. I have to do this for a big file so trying to automate it.
[image: Screenshot]

When I don't give any namespace in the file command then the column is replaced by underscore in the outliner which is exactly what I need like below. But instead of the filename as a default prefix I want "hello" in the outliner. Is this easier to achieve?

[image]

Also if I give namespace as ":" then I don't even get any namespace and column. So adding prefix is another option but that's only available in MEl.

Comment: You can not change this. its on purpose a character not normally allowed in names. Dont use namespaces if this is a problem for you. You just dont gain the benefits of isolation in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maya uses `:` as namespace and doesn't [seem](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/GUID-DD72DBEC-4B6D-4473-A4C5-CDA80DB8FAEB.htm,topicNumber=d30e127332) to be flexible about it.

> The colon (':') character is the separator used to separate the names
>   of namespaces and nodes instead of the slash ('/') or backslash ('\')
>   character.

The code below might be helpful in replacing `hello:` with `hello_`:

```
import pymel.core as pc
pc.namespace(set = ":")         # just in case if there is any preset namespace

for obj in pc.ls(rn=False):     # Referenced objects cannot be renamed
    if "hello:" in obj:
        pc.rename(obj, obj.replace(":", "_"))
```

Namespaces sure can be [removed](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/GUID-DD72DBEC-4B6D-4473-A4C5-CDA80DB8FAEB.htm,topicNumber=d30e127332).

The [renamingPrefix](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/file.html#flagrenamingPrefix) can be used while importing file to resolve nodes with prefixes instead of namespace. In your case `cmd.file(,,rpr = "hello",,,)` could be used.

Comment: Namespaced names can be fixed with rename, but you may also need to remove the namespace with namespace(rm=True).  The namespace sits around in the file even if it's empty - so, for example, if you have a namespace foo you can't also have an object named 'foo'.

Comment: Doesn't `pc.namespace(set = ":")` serve the same purpose? That thing you mention about namespaces could be true, can't confirm right now, but is not explicitly documented. The closest thing I found was [*"Like objects, the names of namespaces must be unique within another namespace."*](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/namespace.html). Plus currently I can't think of a reason why they haven't allowed it, maybe to avoid complexity on their end.

Comment: @theodox Just confirmed it and it definitely is the case.

Comment: namespaces have to be unique in maya because the only way mel/python cmds identifies anything is as a string name (there's no handles or unique ids or other ways to hold on to an object without a name). In order to edit namespaces you need to have their names - which means nothing else can have the same name. It's a dumb system, I think, but it's pretty set in stone after 18 years :(

Comment: namespace -set will force all new operations to be in the namespace you specify. It doesn't rename things. You can use namespace -mv to move objects from one ns to another, but it does not like name clashses

Comment: @theodox one more thing that is worth pointing out, that I just checked, is that if the namespace exists but is empty (contains no object) it will not be saved/preserved to a file upon saving. i.e it will last as long as the current scene and will not be recreated in case that scene was saved and opened in a new scene.